# Statement to come true if both criteria are met

Tags: excel, vba, automation, vlookup

I am trying since many hours as of how the statement will come true if 2 criterias are met

Let suppose I have employees name mentioned below
David
Peter
Johnson
Ashley

Let suppose If i need to check if employee Name "David" is present on 24-August 2022 and if both conditions are met the statement should return "Available" and vice versa

currently the formula i am using is

=IF(AND(B2=Shee2!F$2:F$2000, A2=Sheet2!B$2:B$2000), "Available!", "Not Available")

If i copy paste the formula in a same sequence of Employee name mentioned the gives correct answer.

However if i write Ashley in Row 3 instead of Johnson it gives incorrect answer. The motive is where-ever in the column if both conditions (i.e. Same Date and "Same Employee Name" are found the statement should return with "Available" in other words If Ashley was either mentioned in Row 3 or Row 15 with the required date the statement should come true/Available.

I hope i am able to clarify. Can someone please please help

Comment: Are you using an array formula? Would `Countifs` be a easier?  Can you show some sample data, will help to diagnose.

Comment: Perhaps "IF(AND(B2=Shee2!F$2:F$2000" should be IF(AND(B2=Sheet2!F$2:F$2000, but maybe vlookup(B2,Sheet2!F$2:F$2000,1,0) would work better. Then consider adding iferror().

Comment: Array is not working for me in this condition, if still gives the incorrect value, definitely i would not be using it wisefly.

Comment: @SolarMike Dear Friend let me try your formula and i will get back to you in a min

Comment: @SolarMike there are 2 conditions which needs to be met, in the above formula i think i can define 1 condition only. As mentioned above, it is important that both criteria or condition should be met, can you please help if any other method or formula can be used

Comment: I showed you how to set 1, you can duplicate it to set the second. However, did you try correcting the name error that you show in your own expression?

Comment: @Dominique asked that twice already...

Comment: @SolarMike Can you please write the complete formula for me

Comment: AND(iferror(vlookup(B2,Sheet2!F$2:F$2000,1,0),0),iferror(vlookup(A2,Sheet2!B$2:B$2000,1,0),0)) So, with that, if you have no other errors the rest of your expression show work. NOTE I have corrected the shee to sheet.

Comment: Dear @SolarMike it shows #Value! what should i do

Answer (score 0):

So, as a test I set this up:

[image]

Which shows the structure returning True, which will allow your if() to return the text "Available".

If it does not work on your sheet, then check the data in cells A2 & B2 as well as the data in column F, as something is not correct.

Comment: Let me try this one thanks

Comment: Still giving the same #Value! . Please note there are 2 worksheets in the same workbook, i need to check in sheet2 if Employee Name and Date criteria are met than the value should return true/Available. the formula i have written is =AND(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!C$1:C$2000,1,0),0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A$1:A$2000,1,0),0))

Comment: In Sheet1 Column B is blank. Need to check the value in Column A and Column C

Comment: So, in your comment you show the formula: =AND(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!C$1:C$2000,1,0),0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A$1:A$2000,1,0),0)) and thsn state you are checking in sheet 2. However, in both vlookups you are checking sheet 1.

Comment: Dear @SolarMike Can see my latest answer i have posted below with picture. Top picture shows the fields from Sheet1 and Second picture shows the result in Sheet2.,

Comment: @Salman well you need to check the detail - my test works. And I am not going to repeat it just to show it working across two sheets because it will work.

Comment: okay i will check in detail again. thank you so much for time and attention @solarmike

Comment: Dear @solarMike In  your provided example you have lookup the value of A2 and B2 in column G. Whereas in my condition there is slight difference....... i Need to compare/match/lookup the values available in Sheet2 column A2 with Sheet1 Column A2 and second criteria to be checked is in Sheet2 Column B2 with Sheet1 Column C2. In this case there are 2 criteria in 4 columns. i hope you have understood the query. I will be thankful if any help provided