# Condition should return true if both criteria are met

Tags: excel, vba, automation, vlookup

I am trying since many hours as of how the statement will come true or false based on 2 different criteria. I have 2 worksheets in this scenario.

In Sheet1 I have multiple columns including Date, Age, Gender, Name of employee, joining date, etc. ranging from row 1 to row 2000.

In Sheet2 I have put just 2 columns "Date" and "Name of Employee", and in sheet2 (for checking purpose) I "Date" column i have added Date (e.g. 22-August-22) and in next column I have added "Name of employee" (e.g. David), now i would like to see/match/lookup if David was present on 22-August-22 for confirmation and if both (22-August 22 and DAvid) is available in Sheet1, therefore in a month i need to check all the employees name with different dates multiple times.

Therefore the motive is if a particular employee "E.g. David" was present on August 22, the condition should come true, however if David was not present on 22-August the condition should return false. there are many employees for whom i need check these kind of status.

For this i have used multiple formulas but could not get the desired results. one of stackoverflow friend has suggested a formula which is fulfilling the goal but meeting only 1 condition which is Name however it is not considering the Date.

E.g. In sheet 2 if i only mention the name of employee the condition is returning true, whereas the formula should also check that the name with required date should be matched, and if any of them not met the condition should return false

The formula I am using is

```
=AND(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!A$3:A$2000,1,0),0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet1!B$3:B$2000,1,0),0))
```

I have also used the other formulas but could not get desired results

```
=AND(vlookup(A3,Sheet1!A$3:A$2000,1,0),vlookup(A3,Sheet1!B$3:B$2000,1,0))
```

Please see the examples in below mentioned screenshots as well

[image]

[image]

I shall remain thankful if anyone out of could resolve the problem by suggesting any formula or any VBA code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statement to come true if both criteria are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457928/statement-to-come-true-if-both-criteria-are-met)

Comment: @SolarMike Dear Mike, good to see you, i have tested your formula carefully. however this is meeting 1 condition only which is Name of employee but not considering "Date" ,therefore i decided to ask the question again,

Comment: Then you need to check how to deal with dates as they are challenging - formats etc make a difference. But, imho, this is a duplicate - others will decide.

Comment: Exactly!! since dates are variable and changes everyday therefore i understand it is difficult to deal with them where 1 column contains numeric and second columns contains alphabets.  I wish anyone who is expert in VBA can advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Countifs should work, `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A2)`, if it returns 0 then the employee isn't available that day, if it returns any other number they were although I think you shouldn't get more than 1.

Comment: Yes it is working, i am checking in detail. O Wow

Comment: Dear @Stuart i have no words to say thank you, however, Thank you So much for kindness and help

Comment: @Salman if this works for you then you should at least accept the answer and even vote for it. The site needs that to keep track of open and completed questions.

Comment: @Stuart please advise how to vote or accept the answer, i am sorry i will definitely do it. but i do not know which button to click or how to vote

Comment: i have clicked the button, hopefully it is accept, Thanks @Stuart